# Почему GameObject.GetComponent<T>() возвращает null, Unity 2018

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity выдает сразу 2 ошибки:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TreeTile.StartUp (Vector3Int position, UnityEngine.Tilemaps.ITilemap tilemap, UnityEngine.GameObject go) (at Assets/Scripts/TileScripts/TreeTile.cs:12)

Error running StartUp for Tile.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TreeTile.StartUp (Vector3Int position, UnityEngine.Tilemaps.ITilemap tilemap, UnityEngine.GameObject go) (at Assets/Scripts/TileScripts/TreeTile.cs:12)
```

которые указывают на строку

```
    go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sorting = -position.y * 2;
```

Понимаю, что где-то ссылаюсь на `null`, но где - понять не могу.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class TreeTile : Tile
{

    public override bool StartUp(Vector3Int position, ITilemap tilemap, GameObject go)
    {
        go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = -position.y * 2;
        return base.StartUp(position, tilemap, go);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/Tiles/Treetile")]
    public static void CreateTreetile()
    {
        string path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanelInProject("Save Treetile", "New Treetile", "asset", "Save Treetile", "Assets");
        if (path == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TreeTile>(), path);
    }

#endif

}
```

Для справки: я пытаюсь добавить в тайловую палитру (Tile Palette) префаб дерева с колайдером и объектом. Это мне, вроде, удалось, но деревья ставились друг на друга. Я использую новый скрипт, чтобы они не наслаивались и сортировались. Проект компилируется, всё запускается и отображается без проблем. Но вот сама ошибка печатается, и это напрягает.

Ниже приведены картинки для наглядности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы добавили не весь код, что за закрывающая фигурная скобка в методе `StartUp`?

Comment: опечатка, допустил при редактиировании

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, null вы получаете от метода `GetComponent<T>()`, т.к. к объекту не прикреплен искомый компонент:

[GetComponent Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

> Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one
>   attached, **null if it doesn't**.

---

Скорее всего банальная человеческая ошибка, чтобы "не забывать" вешать необходимые компоненты на префабы - пользуйтесь [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html):

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class TreeTile : Tile
...
```

Причем данный атрибут можно установить на базовый класс `Tile`, и он, очевидно, будет работать и для всех его потомков.

---

**UPDATE**

[Изучив документацию по теме тайлов в Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.TileBase.StartUp.html) стало ясно, что метод `StartUp` используется для кастомного кода для кастомных спрайтов. Причем этот метод вызывается, видимо, для инициализации самой TilePallete, а значит не для инстанциированных объектов.

Другими словами Unity за кулисами не передает никакой объект параметром в `StartUp`, что в этой строке:

```
go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sorting = ...;
```

Равносильно

```
null.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sorting = ...;
```

Если посмотреть на пример реализации собственных тайлов в API, видно, что в переопределенном `StartUp` методе нужно вручную проверять условие `go != null`:

```
public override bool StartUp(Vector3Int location, ITilemap tilemap, GameObject go)
{
    if (go != null)
    {
        go.transform.rotation = Random.rotation;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! В будущем обязательно поможет, но проблему это, к сожалению, не решило. Проект компилируется, всё запускается и отображается без проблем. Но вот сама ошибка печатается, и это напрягает.
Для справки скажу, что я пытаюсь в тайловую карту занести префаб со скриптом. Может где-то там накосячил, но найти ошибку - не удаётся (

Comment: @Fadiuty тогда добавьте полный код и вообще всю информацию в вопрос

Comment: я добавил больше информации, может так лучше будет)

Comment: И если ответ вам помог, поставьте ему галочку.

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь! Добавление if (go != null) действительно помогло. Впредь буду более тщательно изучать документацию!